# How does the release work in ARC based projects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I know there are lot of questions on this topic. I have never worked on Non ARC based project.

I have strong & weak property as follows

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray *data1;
@property(unsafe_unretained, nonatomic)NSArray *data2;
```

I have seen in some places people explicitly make the data nil in the viewDidUnload.

i.e

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    self.data1=nil;
    self.data2=nil;
}
```

My question is if I dont do this in my case(I mean if I dont make the data1 and data2  nil

in the viewDidUnload), Will ARC release the objects automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ARC will automatically release all strong-reference properties/variables just before the destruction of the parent object. As for "weak" references, they are not retained/released (that's the same with or without ARC).

Setting `self.data1 = nil` in `viewDidUnload` is usually unnecessary, but sometimes you want to make it obvious to show where your referenced object is released. If you want to be sure that your `data1` is released right here at this line of code, use the code you have. If you don't care when and where it's released, you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help.

Comment: btw, viewDidUnload is deprecated. Who can explain the difference between unsafe_unretained and weak modifiers?

Comment: weak references become nil when the object the are pointing to is deallocated, unsafe references do not (i.e. dangling pointer just like before ARC).  You should only use unsafe for compatibility reasons.

Comment: where should I set the unsafe_unretained to nil ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they will be released when your view controller is deallocated. `viewDidUnload` (no longer called as of iOS 6) is not the same as `dealloc`, nor is it an "opposite" of `viewDidLoad` - it was only called in low memory situations, when a view was off screen.

Any transient, memory-hogging objects should be set to nil in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` - ARC will *not* do that automatically for you.